# Setters for class variables

Tags: python, class, attributes, setter

I have a simple class within a module named `foo.py`:

```
class Foo
    foo = 1
```

that I import into other modules (`bar.py` and `baz.py`) and I alter the class variable `foo` within these other modules, e.g.:

```
# bar.py

from foo import Foo
print(Foo.foo) # should print 1.
Foo.foo = 2
```

and

```
# baz.py

from foo import Foo

print(Foo.foo) # should print 2.
Foo.foo = 3
```

The changes to `Foo.foo` however should be checked before they are set. Therefore, I'm currently using a setter method in `Foo`:

```
# foo.py

@classmethod
def set_foo(cls, new_foo):
    # do some checks on the supplied new_foo, then set foo.
    cls.foo = new_foo
```

**Is this the pythonic way to set a class variable?** Or are there better methods (similar to the `@property a` and `@a.setter` declarations for instance variables)? I want the class variable `foo` to persist when importing `Foo` in these other modules and don't really want to make an instance of `Foo` as it's more of a class thing I guess.

Thanks SO ;-)

Comment: To use a `property`, it would have to be defined on the metaclass. This @classmethod approach doesn't seem terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a little magic, this can be done relatively sanely by using the descriptor protocol.

```
class FooDescriptor:

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj._foo

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(obj, type):
            # disable instance name shadowing for sanity's sake
            raise AttributeError("this attribute should be set on the class object")
        obj._foo = value + "!!"


class FooMeta(type):

    foo = FooDescriptor()

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, namespace):
        # pluck the "foo" attr out of the class namespace,
        # and swap in our descriptor in its place
        namespace["_foo"] = namespace.pop("foo", "(default foo val)")
        namespace["foo"] = FooMeta.foo
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, namespace)
```

When constructing a class `Foo`, this will replace the `foo` class attribute defined in the normal declarative fashion with a data descriptor (to provide custom getters and setters). We will be storing the raw "unmanaged" value in `Foo._foo` instead.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta): 
...     foo = "foo0" 
... 
>>> obj = Foo() 
>>> obj.foo  # accessible from instance, like a class attr
'foo0'
>>> Foo.foo  # accessible from class
'foo0'
>>> Foo.foo = "foo1"  # setattr has magic, this will add exclams
>>> obj.foo
'foo1!!'
>>> Foo.foo
'foo1!!'
>>> vars(obj)  # still no instance attributes
{}
>>> type(Foo).foo  # who does the trick?
<__main__.FooDescriptor at 0xcafef00d>
>>> obj.foo = "boom"  # prevent name shadowing (optional!)
AttributeError: this attribute should be set on the class object
```

Comment: Very detailed and interesting approach, thank you. It does, however, seem exceptionally overkill considering how easy it is to achieve for instance variables. I assume to make this more general, you call it `ClassVariableDescriptor` and `ClassVariableMeta` for instancE?

Comment: It's only so "easy" to achieve for instance variables because the stdlib provides `@property` for that, yet there is no stdlib "classproperty". If you look at the pure python implementation of `property` in the descriptor guide, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties), you will see all the getters and setters implemented in a similar way. Overkill? Yes, perhaps - if you're not a framework author, then a plain old classmethod setter would probably be a more pragmatic choice.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to inherit from `Foo`, be aware that the `classmethod` will modify the attribute of the *calling instance's class*.

```
class Base:

    class_variable = 'base'

    @classmethod
    def set_cvar(cls, value):
        cls.class_variable = value

class Derived(Base):

    pass

Derived.set_cvar('derived')
print(Base.class_variable)
print(Derived.class_variable)
```

Output:

```
base
derived
```

This may (probably will be), or may not, be what you want. The alternative is to instead use a `staticmethod` and name your class explicitly.

In general, though, I would consider this a good method.

Comment: Thanks. I don't plan on subclassing this. Instead `Foo` is an input output class and I can configure `bar` the input directory throughout a package.

Comment: See edit to the question to clarify what I'm after. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I think the 'pythonic way', if there is any, to use the a.setter, using _ format:

```
@property
def bar(self):
    return self._bar

@bar.setter
def environment(self, bar):
    # do some checks on the supplied bar, then set
    self._bar = bar
```

In that way _bar is 'private' and you can you 'bar' in your code when you want to set it.