# Update a module variable accross all Imports

Tags: python, dynamic-import

I would like to update a module variable dynamically even after imports

```
mod
   __init__.py
      foo = 'some'
      def update_foo(val):
          updates foo
```

when running the code

```
import foo
import foo as f

print(foo)
'some'
print(f)
'some'

update_foo('other')

print(foo)
'other'

print(f)
'other'
```

Can someone recommend a pythonic approach for this?
I have tried defining this as a class method by following this link(https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645482). Is there any elegant way to achieve this? I would like to ideally refer to foo directly. My approach now makes me access it by Foo.foo.

Comment: You mean `from Foo import foo`?

Comment: `foo` is the module object.  I don't see how `print(foo)` would ever produce "some".

Comment: @Mohamedneyaz: Please update your code, in order to make it easier to understand and reproducible.